# How can I figure out if a packet is a TCP Keep-Alive?

Tags: tcp

Wireshark and Network Monitor provide filters for this but I want to know how can I infer whether a packet is a TCP Keep-Alive or Keep-Alive Ack by looking at the header or payload.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A TCP keep-alive packet is an ACK with the sequence number set to one less than the 
current sequence number for the connection.

Comment: Exactly, here is the TCP keep-alive specification:
<https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-101>

Answer (score 1):

Here's what [Wireshark says](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvTCPAnalysis.html) about a keep-alive ACK:

> Set when all of the following are true:
>
> - The segment size is zero.
> - The window size is non-zero and hasn’t changed.
> - The current sequence number is the same as the next expected sequence number.
>   -The current acknowledgement number is the same as the last-seen acknowledgement number.
> - The most recently seen packet in the reverse direction was a keepalive.
> - The packet is not a SYN, FIN, or RST.